# How to resample friendships when bootstrapping by individuals

Tags: bootstrap, social-network

Sheesh, I'm really confused.

So, I have a dataset of individuals, and a dataset of their friendships. I want to test whether a particular (numeric) variable is correlated among friends. To do this,
I am bootstrap resampling individuals.

My original data looks like:

```
NAME  VARIABLE
Joe   1
Sam   3
Pete  2
...   ...
```

with a friendship network like:

```
FRIEND1   FRIEND2
Joe       Pete
Joe       Sam
Sam       Jill
...       ...
```

My basic statistic is created by correlating friend 1's variable with friend 2's variable. That is, I join my tables to create:

```
VARIABLE1 FRIEND1 FRIEND2 VARIABLE2
1         Joe     Pete     2
1         Joe     Sam      3
3         Sam     Jill     4
```

Standard errors will be wrong, of course, because each friend may appear many times in the data.

So, I resample individuals with replacement. When I do this, I might get Joe's name 2 times and Pete's name 3 times. I then want to recreate the friendship network and rerun my correlation. By doing this many times, I will get the 
sampling distribution of my statistic.

But, how many times should the Joe-Pete friendship appear in the new data? I guess 2*3 = 6 times... is that right?

Examples in R would be welcome, but mostly I want to know how to think about this. (I'm even confused... is it legitimate to resample at individual level, given that by assumption friends' data is correlated... argh!!!)

Comment: It is not clear for me what and why do you want to resample..? Your second question: "But, how many times should the Joe-Pete friendship appear in the new data?" is even more unclear -- bootstrap will give you random number of pairs so what are you counting here..?

Comment: To avoid any ambiguity, can you precise if your variable is numerical, categorical or ordinal ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "correlated among friends"? One possible interpretation--which assumes you didn't really mean "correlated," but meant "dependent"--is that the distribution of unordered pairs of the variables among the friends somehow differs from the distribution of such pairs among non-friends. I suspect you implicitly have in mind some metric to compare values of those variables and that you might mean that the variables tend to be closer between friends than between non-friends.  But I'm just guessing... .  If I'm correct, what is the metric?

Comment: @Tim: I am bootstrapping individuals, not pairs. Let's assume that I get Joe's name twice, and Pete's name 3 times. Then, how many times should the Joe-Pete friendship appear?

Comment: @brumar : the variable is numeric.

Comment: @whuber : I simply mean that friends' values are correlated. So, if you made a dataset of friend 1's value, and friend 2's value, with one row for every pair of friends in the _population_, then those values would be correlated. I'll clarify this in the text.

Comment: @dash2 "correlation" has a precise meaning in statistics, it implies that a mathematical relation (by default linear) describes well their dependence. Is it really what you look for ? Is the reformulation suggested by whuber acceptable to you ? If not, why?

Comment: @brumar I am indeed looking for a linear correlation. I appreciate that there are other forms of dependence, but I am relaxed about that. In this particular case, as often in applied research, more complex forms of dependence, that did not also cause a non-zero correlation, would be implausible.

Comment: @dash2 I fail to see how a linear correlation is imaginable here. I ll suggest to take a mathematical standpoint here. V1 and V2 are symetric (to not say the same variable). Whatever the resampling you are doing you arbitraly organize your friend pairs by choosing which guy has V1 and which guy has V2. Whatever the relation you are looking for between the two, it must respect f(V1)=V2 and V1=f(V2). Among bijective functions, only the identity function can work.

Comment: Although you might get some useful answers here, what you are trying to do is probably very difficult. I see that "Bootstrap a network, non-parametrically" is one of the items on Cosma Shalizi's list of "Things I wish I knew how to do" in his notebook pages (and he is one of the world's leading statisticians at the moment.)

Comment: @brumar: I do not agree. Suppose Pete is friends with Jim Sam is friends with Al; and Tim is friends with Zac. If Pete and Jim are both 6 feet tall, while Sam and Al are 5 feet tall, and Tim and Zac are both 4 feet tall, then there is a positive linear correlation between friends' height. Yes, if height was a deterministic function of friends' height then only the identity function would work, but the relationship is statistical, not deterministic.

Comment: @dash2 the backbone of linear correlation is still a mathematical function. You won't find any suitable $a,b$ where both $X2=aX1+b$ and $X1=aX2+b$ reach statistical significance. From your example, I realized that maybe the friendship relationship you are considering is asymetric. If this is not the case,because I can order the pair as I want and not getting the linear correlation mentioned. Is it the case ?

Comment: @brumar. Here is some R code. `tmp <- data.frame(name = LETTERS, hairlength = 1:26 + rnorm(26));   tmp$friend = LETTERS[c(2:26,1)];   frs <- left_join(tmp, tmp, by = c('friend'='name'));   plot(frs$hairlength.x, frs$hairlength.y); cor.test(frs$hairlength.x, frs$hairlength.y); s <- sample(1:26, 13); frs[s,] <- frs[s, c(3,4,1,2,5)];  plot(frs$hairlength.x, frs$hairlength.y); cor.test(frs$hairlength.x, frs$hairlength.y)` A significant correlation survives randomly permuting friends. That said, the issue you address does have important ramifications - see Manski (1993).

Answer (score 3):

I don't feel ultra confident on my answer, but I would be interested to be reviewed if necessary. If I were you, I would go for a permutation test because it does not suffer from the non-independence you are pointing. Pick a good statistic that represents the effect you are studying. Something like $$S=\sum_{i,j} |V(i)-V(j)|*I_{i,j}$$ with $I_{i,j}=1$ if $i$ and $j$ are connected (0 otherwise). After computing this statistic for your data-set, do it for each permutation of your data by shuffling the `VARIABLE` column.

```
NAME  VAR             NAME  VAR    NAME  VAR    NAME  VAR
Joe   1               Joe   2      Joe   5      Joe   5
Sam   3               Sam   3      Sam   3      Sam   3       ....
Pete  2               Pete  1      Pete  2      Pete  1
John  5               John  5      John  1      John  2
...   ...             ...   ...    ...   ...    ...   ...
Original data-set     data-set1    data-set2    data-set3      ....
```

In `r` this can be done with the built-in function `sample` on the column you wish to shuffle. As we do a permutation test (not a bootstrap procedure) there is no replacement.

For each new data-set, compute your $S_k$ score. If your hypothesis is true, your $S_k$ scores must be most of the time higher than $S$.

Your p-value is the number of times your permuted set get better or equal $S_k$ score than your original S.

Comment: This looks like a good idea--but could you be more explicit about what you mean by "breaking and redistributing"?  The validity of the result appears to rely on exactly how that is carried out.

Comment: This is a good idea and I might well do it. But, I think the original question (how to resample a network?) still deserves a specific answer, because I've seen it done a fair bit.

Comment: I think you are right. But I personally think that there is no general answer. It depends on your goal. You can chose to preserve the structure and only resampling the values (as I did in my answer). This is in line with the sole interpretation of your goal I can come up with. Another goal being given, I guess you can come up with procedures could maybe involve resampling the network itself.